# Ubuntu is running in low graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my laptop dell 1564. Due to some problem i run the ubuntu setup again. after words i found the dialog box with the message that "Ubuntu is running in low graphics mode" Ubuntu cannot start. Can any one explain me or with the site refference that how can i reinstall the graphics card. I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for superuser.com because it is related to computer software and not programming.

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
sudo su
X -configure
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

reboot the machine and try.

If doesn't work, paste here /etc/X11/xorg.conf

and eventually: /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this error when I upgraded from 9.04 to 10.04. At first, I thought there is problem with my installation so I reinstalled 10.04. But then after I updated the libraries and restarted my PC, same old error occured again. It is really wasting my time! My whole weekend was wasted! What the hell!

The best thing I did was downgrade to 9.04 because I know that is a bug that the programmers didn't notice. And also 10.04 is under Alpha stage, so expect bugs.

Comment: I also suspect it's a hardware/software issue. Some say that I should also download a driver for my video card...Mmm... still frustrating because I expected that all drivers are available.